# AWS Cloudwatch Dashboard metric graph text size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

We have a series of dashboards, some of which have numerical values - for instance one shows the number of support tickets we have open/triage/referred.

Is it possible to change the text size in "graph"? At the moment, the number overflow the box.

This is the current JSON:

```
{
"metrics": [
    [ "Freshdesk", "TechnicalTeam-Open", { "label": "Open" } ],
    [ ".", "TechnicalTeam-Pending", { "label": "Pending" } ],
    [ ".", "TechnicalTeam-Triage", { "label": "Triage" } ],
    [ ".", "TechnicalTeam-Referred", { "label": "Referred" } ]
],
"view": "singleValue",
"region": "eu-west-2",
"period": 300,
"singleValueFullPrecision": true,
"liveData": true,
"title": " ",
"stat": "Average"
}
```

Any advise/help, gratefully received :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/CloudWatch-Dashboard-Body-Structure.html#CloudWatch-Dashboard-Properties-Rendering-Object-Format, text size of the rendered object can't be changed. You can change the rendered color though, or make the label upper-cased to make it more visible.